OneDrive / Excel VBA - Send Request to All Participants
I feel like I've searched the web and can find very little about the functionality of OneDrive as it relates to Excel / VBA.
I'm trying to keep it real simple to begin with: I'm trying to "announce" on all users' screens, i.e. "Joey has entered the chat". How can I force a command (i.e. Msgbox) to all users that are currently in the shared Excel spreadsheet?
I've tried the following, side-by-side another user, both using the Excel App with content enabled:
'Immediate window: results in only me seeing the pop-up
MsgBox "Joey has entered the chat!"

'Module: results in only me seeing the pop-up and Userform
Public Sub testAnnouncement()
    MsgBox "Joey has entered the chat!"
    UserForm1.Show
End Sub

'Changing a cell on a worksheet: results in only the person to change the cell to see the pop-up
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Address = "$A$1" Then
        MsgBox "Joey has entered the chat!"
    End If
End Sub

Perhaps I'm missing something? Any help would be appreciated; thank you.

Could you have a Power Automate job running that polls the workbook - have Workbook_Open put the users name in a worksheet and Workbook_Close remove it again. The PA job sees who has been added/left since the last check. If you do this polling within the workbook it will tie up the UI

There's nothing built-in which allows for this type of between-user interaction when in "collaborative editing" mode.
